# Как прикрепить файл к форме заявки woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброй ночи. Появилась нужда сделать возможным прикрепить 1 файл к форме заявки woocommerce, чтобы при отправке заявки на почту - этот файл прикреплялся. Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Что вы называете заявкой woocommerce? Оформление заказа на странице checkout?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться плагином [WooCommerce Checkout Manager](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/). Он позволяет создавать дополнительные поля 15 типов: Text Input, Text Area, Password, Radio Button, Check Box, Select Options, Date Picker, Time Picker, Color Picker, Heading, Multi-Select, Multi-Checkbox, Country, State, **File Picker**.

Comment: А без плагина? Может грузить на сервер и прикреплять ссылку через стандартное поле?

Comment: Без плагина я знаю, как сделать текстовое поле, например. Можно использовать его как ссылку на файл. Если надо, напишу.

Comment: Текстовое поля я смогу сделать через Checkout Fields. Вот как мне загрузить файл и прикрепить ссылку при отправке формы